# Get Formatted PowerPoint 2010 Slide Notes

Tags: office-automation, powerpoint-2010

Using the following C# code I can get the raw text.  What I need, however, is a way to get the formatting (bold, italics, etc) that goes along with the text.

```
string noteText;

for ( var i = 1; i <= mySlide.NotesPage.Shapes.Count; i++ )
{
   var noteShape = mySlide.NotesPage.Shapes[i];

   if ( noteShape.Type == OfficeCore.MsoShapeType.msoPlaceholder )
   {
      if ( noteShape.PlaceholderFormat.Type == PowerPoint.PpPlaceholderType.ppPlaceholderBody )
      {
         if ( noteShape.HasTextFrame == OfficeCore.MsoTriState.msoTrue )
         {
            if ( noteShape.TextFrame2.HasText == OfficeCore.MsoTriState.msoTrue )
            {
               noteText = noteShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text;
               break;
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Can anyone help?